# How can I programatically test if server is up?

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell

I've a [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) automation script, running forever. Part of the requirement is a graceful termination if server is down.

How can I programmatically determine if server is up before making any API calls?

I'm using PowerShell (with .Net dlls), and C#.

Comment: Maybe you could ping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ping the server using [`Test-Connection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx):

```
Test-Connection servername -Count 1 -Quiet
```

This returns true/false thanks to the `-Quiet` option:

> Suppresses all errors and returns `$True` if any pings succeeded and `$False` if all failed.

`-Count 1` makes it return faster but you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Lucas Trzesniewski.